# How can I output a KnockoutJs value in an HTML comment

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have a foreach loop that looks something like this in a slimmed version.

```
<div data-bind="foreach: articles">
     <h1 data-bind="text: title"></h1>
</div>
```

Now I want to add a HTML comment with a value from the binding. The resulting HTML should be rendered like this.

```
<div data-bind="foreach: articles">
     <h1 data-bind="text: myTitle">My title</h1>
     <!-- My property value -->
</div>
```

I want "< ! -- My property value - - >" to come from a property in the current foreach binding. I hoped it would be possible with something simple as

```
<!-- myProperty -->
```

Is this possible and if it is, how can I accomplish this?
Thanks.

**EDIT:**
My solution that I don't like and try to replace with a "good" solution.

```
<div data-bind="foreach: articles">
     <h1 data-bind="text: myTitle">My title</h1>
     <p style="display:none;" data-bind="html: $root.commentValue(myProperty)"></p>
</div>

self.commentValue = function (valueToComment) {
            return '<!-- ' + valueToComment + ' -->';
        }
```

Comment: if you want to render html content try `html:myTitle` in data-bind sample here http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/27668/.

Comment: @supercool That's not going to render as a `HTML comment` and if I understand correctly, that's what OP is looking for.

Comment: If you give it comment html, it will render it. Of course, you have to inspect it in the debugger to see the comment.
http://jsfiddle.net/o0g28zwc/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing that works is this one:

```
<div data-bind="html: '<!--' + WeightInGramms() + '-->'"></div>
```

But it has an obvious side effect: there is also a div rendered.

The solution would be using a virtual element like this:

```
<!-- ko html: "<!--" + WeightInGramms() + '--' + '>' --> 
<!-- /ko -->
```

It nearly works, but there is a big problem: you cannot use `html` binding in a virtual element (apart from the hack of converting `'-->'` into `'--' + '>'` so that it's not confused with the virtual element comment closing).

So, the only possible solution is to create your own [custom binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html), but making it [valid to be used as a virtual element binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-for-virtual-elements.html).

```js
ko.bindingHandlers['comment'] = {
    'init': function(elem, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
        var comment = $('<!--'+value+'-->')[0];
        ko.virtualElements.setDomNodeChildren(elem, [comment]);
    },
    'update': function (elem, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
        var comment = $('<!--'+value+'-->')[0];
        ko.virtualElements.setDomNodeChildren(elem, [comment]);
    }
};

ko.virtualElements.allowedBindings.comment = true;

var vm = {
    aComment: ko.observable("This is a comment")
}

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" data-bind="value: aComment"></div>

<!--ko comment: aComment --><!-- /ko -->
```

It's still no perfect because you cannot delete the virtual binding tags, but it's much cleaner than adding a real tag to include the comment. Note that the custom binding implementation uses the special `ko.virtualElements` API to support virtual elements.

Comment: I feared I would have to render element tags as well and I understand that it's not possible to render a value without them now :) Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Wait... using a custom binding it's not so hard to do. Give me a few minutes, and I'll show you.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the summary i the knockout documentation... You don't have to add an example, if I read the articles through I should understand :) as long as you say it works I'm happy ;)